# Javascript equivilant for MS Excel Standard Deviation (STDEV)

Tags: javascript, excel

I need a javascript function to match the math used in Excel's STDEV function.

When I use the array [1,2,4,6] I get the standard deviation of 1.9202 with every js script I've found.  However, when I run the same array through Excel's STDEV, I get 2.2173.

I'm not a mathematician, but I am trying to convert some excel reports into javascript.  What I'm ultimately looking for is a JavaScript function to do what excel does.

Additionally, I've looked at other people with similar issues, and they spent a while explaining the differences, but gave no code sample, or direct math equation that I can convert to JS.  Any help is appreciated, a javascript function would be most helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing apples with oranges.

The equivalent formula in Excel is STDEVP (i.e. the **population** standard deviation). This will match the Javascript result.

The **population** standard deviation has `sqrt(n)` as the denominator whereas the **unbiased** standard deviation (STDEV) has `sqrt(n - 1)`. `n` is the number of terms making up the standard deviation.

To convert from one to the other, multiply / divide by `sqrt(n / (n - 1))`:

`1.9202 * sqrt(4 / 3) = 2.2173`

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for those who wants to use a library -

[MathJs](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/std.html)

```
math.std(2, 4, 6);                     // returns 2
math.std([2, 4, 6, 8]);                // returns 2.581988897471611
math.std([2, 4, 6, 8], 'uncorrected'); // returns 2.23606797749979
math.std([2, 4, 6, 8], 'biased');      // returns 2
```